# What/How is inside (internal implementation) OSGi framework?

Tags: java, osgi

Heard a lot on the advantage of OSGi framework like Modularity, Versioning and Dynamic install and uninstall on the fly itself. But I am curious to know how it is achieved by OSGi framework? What is internal implementation inside OSGi framework?  Can anyone shed light on classloader mechanism in OSGi!

Comment: If you want to understand the implementation of OSGI, either find the source code and read it, or find and read the design documentation.

Comment: or look at the spec, the spec is quite easy to understand :)

Comment: @AchimNierbeck Hope what you mean is spec from OSGi Alliance : https://www.osgi.org/developer/specifications/

Comment: @ABHIJITHKINI yes, the specification of the OSGi Alliance.

Answer (score 3):

Felix is widely used OSGi implementation. You can find its source code [here](https://github.com/apache/felix/tree/trunk/framework).

If I have to describe how OSGi framework is implemented then it'd be: OSGi framework deals with special kind of packaging units called *bundles* (just like JavaEE deals with WARs, EARs and JARs). For each bundle, a classloader is created that deals with modularity, dynamic imports and imports/exports.

You can also find good books about OSGi - like OSGi in Action.

Comment: OSGI in action rocks, really opened my eyes.